# How to verify all elements on the page?

Tags: java, cucumber

I want to verify if all needed elemants exist on the page.
I can list them in the Examples section for Scenario Outline. For example:

```
  Scenario Outline: I am able to see all elements on My Page
    When I am on my page
    Then I should see the following <element> My Menu
    Examples:
     | element         |
     | MENU button     |
     | MY logo         |
     | MY_1 link       |
     | MY_2 link       |
     | Button_1 button |
     | Button_2 button |  
     | Loggin button   |
```

Each row runs a separate method to verify an element's presence on the page. The problem is - the page is reloaded.
How can the problem be solved in more appropriate way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all using a scenario outline will result in 1 scenario for each element you want to test. This has huge run-time costs, and is not the way to go.

Secondly putting all this information in the scenario is also very expensive and unproductive. Gherkin scenarios are supposed to talk at the business level, not the developer level, so I would rewrite this as

```
Scenario: I am able to see all elements on Foo page
  When I am on foo page
  Then I should see all the foo elements
```

and implement it with something like

```
Then "I should see all the foo elements" do
  expect(should_see_all_foo_elements).to be true
end
```

and now you can make a helper module to make this work

```
module FooPageStepHelper
  def should_see_all_foo_elements
    find('h1', text: /foo/) &&
    ...
  end
end
World FooPageStepHelper
```

Now when the foo page gets a new element, you only have to change one line in one file. Notice how the business need (that all the elemnts should appear on the page) doesn't change when you add or remove elements

*(n.b. you could improve the helper function in a number of ways to get better info when something goes wrong, and even output listing the elements that are present)*

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a scenario outline. You just need a step that verifies all the elements in the table.

```
Scenario: I am able to see all elements on My Page
    When I am on my page
    Then I should see the following elements in My Menu
     | MENU button     |
     | MY logo         |
     | MY_1 link       |
     | MY_2 link       |
     | Button_1 button |
     | Button_2 button |  
     | Loggin button   |
```

Where you can use the table as a array of arrays:

```
Then(/^I should see the following elements in My Menu$/) do |table|
  table.raw.each do |menu_item|
    @my_page_object.menu(menu_item).should == true
  end
end


When(/^I am on my page$/) do
  @my_page_object = MyPageObject.new(browser)
end
```